# Hover state on ipad issue

Tags: javascript

I have a masonry layout with each cell is infact a hyperlink requiring a hover state to be shown.

On ipad (as predicted) the hover states did not display. The client has requested that the links should now need two clicks: once to display the hover state, and a second click to engage the hyperlink - So I used this bit of javascript:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.my_button').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
      });
  });
```

The problem now is that on ipad the hover states now display (which is great), but the second click is being ignored and does nothing.

You can view the live site at http://mayce.derringer.com.au/residential/

Answer (score 1):

> The problem now is that on ipad the hover states now display (which is
>   great), but the second click is being ignored and does nothing.

With

```
e.preventDefault();
```

you prevent the default behaviour so the click/touch will never be able to follow the link. Try like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.my_button').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
          if($(this).hasClass('hover_effect') {
              return; // skip rest of code, so default will happen
                      // which is following the link
          }
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('hover_effect'); // no reason to toggleClass
                                            // cause the seccond click/touch should always go to destination
      });
  });
```

Now probably you want it though that if click/touch on a different `$('.my_button')` you need to remove the `hover_effect` to all the other `my_button(s)` so add

```
$('.my_button').not(this).removeClass('hover_effect');
```

like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.my_button').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
          $('.my_button').not(this).removeClass('hover_effect');
          if($(this).hasClass('hover_effect') {
              return; // skip rest of code 
          }
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('hover_effect'); // no reason to toggleClass
                                            // cause the seccond click/touch should always go to destination
      });
  });
```

I haven't tried the code, but it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but unfortunately it didn't work.
Your solution seems to revert the behaviour of the button back to it's original problem: It activates the hyperlink on first click. No hover state is shown.

Comment: @shanDB well then please also share your HTML and CSS

Comment: error in fiddle: `{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 15,
  "colno": 47
}`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more research, and I have come up with this solution which works:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.middle').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        //This will return true after the first click
        //and preventDefault won't be called.
        if(!$(this).hasClass('nav_returnlink'))
            e.preventDefault();

        $(this).addClass('nav_returnlink');
    });
});
```